# Перелистывание html (WebView)

Tags: xml, android, html

Как реализовать аналог gallery для изображений, где вместо изображений будет WebView?
В галерею не запихивается (или у меня не получилось) использование конструкции:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hS"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lL"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wV1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 >
                </WebView>
            <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/wV2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"              
                    >
            </WebView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Не помогает, при открытии html. На экране ничего не отображается. Задача в том, чтобы перемещаться между двумя страницами путем перелистывания влево-вправо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как варианты предложу следующие примеры:

1. [Хорошая](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/131889/) реализация с помощью `ViewPager`. Можно применить любые UI элементы. ([коммент](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/131889/#comment_4379987), как сделать наподобие `Gallery`).
2. С того же [хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/118482/), реализация с помощью `ViewFlipper`. Также немного переработать и сделать с `WebView`.
3. Ну и на всякий пара примеров: [1](http://code.google.com/p/deezapps-widgets/) и [2](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/).